# Why are delegates set to weak references instead of strong?

Tags: ios, delegates, datasource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios confused about strong/weak references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458286/ios-confused-about-strong-weak-references)

I am new to ios development and was reading the Stanford's Lecture Notes on delegates. Why are delegates set to be weak references instead of strong?

Comment: Short Answer: To prevent retain cycles. Also there are cases where you will have a strong reference to a delegate (E.g. [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest:delegate:))

Comment: Because your object graph will have a circular reference (a retain cycle) and the objects referencing each other will never be deallocated. A good explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12802396/558933